# Do we really need an [origin] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

At first glance I thought [origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/origin) would be about mathematical origins, but yeah source control origins apply too. Should it be deleted?

Comment: Well there's only one question with that tag.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yeah, so what do we do with new ambiguous tags?

Comment: Can anyone be an expert in "origin" in either sense?

Comment: Well, it was [created 14 hours ago by Christopher Wallace](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10588291/revisions) .  I'm not sure what that user intended.  They also added the rather ambiguous [tag:master] tag.

Comment: Wow, looking at the [tag:master] tag, it's really terribly ambiguous and deserves its own meta post.

Comment: I say burn it.  The [git] tag describes the question perfectly well.  We don't need tags for every class, concept and feature under the sun.  Just for the major/important concepts.

Comment: I am pretty sure this can be misused or misinterpreted. I know of `background-origin` in CSS and some users can end up tagging background and origin (this tag). So it might be better to do away with this tag completely.

Comment: EA have also talked about making an api for their Origin but I haven't managed to find one as of yet

Comment: When you type in a tag name that is new, you get a warning. If you mean to create a tag, go ahead - and then create the _about_ entries too. That way, even with one only one question, there's info for the community to make reasonable judgments with.

Answer (score 5):

Yep. Done - before I knew of this question. It was pretty clearly a case of typing the question into the tags field. If a previous editor disagrees, they can put the tag back.

I'd run into another question that had created a new low-value tag, which prompted me to look at the [new tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new) list and get the broom out.

The risk of leaving low-value tags like this around for even a short time is that they can get piled upon. Take [app-development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/app-development) for instance, which was created June 29 for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31109022/how-to-build-a-cross-platform-app, then used today with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31175410/phonegap-cordova-how-to-add-php-support.

If you see a new tag created, and you are confident it's of low value, delete it. If there are other edits that would improve the question, make them at the same time. If your edit must go through a review queue, make sure your note explains that you're burninating the tag, hopefully the reviewers will read your explanation and agree.

If you're unsure whether a tag has value, move on - trust that people with more domain knowledge can make that determination. No need to add traffic to Meta. (Everybody! Back to work!)

Comment: This post inspired a [blog post](https://mogsdad.wordpress.com/2015/07/02/stackoverflow-lost-found-part-1/).